# Python quit unexpectedly on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I have installed python3 from the [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

When I try to run 'python3', it quits and give these information:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>       ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00007fff960a93c0 (most recent call first):
>       Abort trap: 6

Before that, I try to install python3 from Homebrew.

I don't remember whether I have to delete the build in python frameworks in the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

os : macOS

by the way, the IDLE works well

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can reinstall a corrupted Python environment like this:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python python@2
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install python python@2
```

I had a similar "quit unexpectedly" issue and this resolved it for me. `pip` and `pip3` are both working fine after without messing with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Then:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```